# NSURLConnection's didReceiveData Not Working in dispatch_async Block

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I am trying to validate a user's token before loading a URL via NSURLConnection.

My problem is that if I start the NSURLConnection within the `dispatch_async` block (see 1 below), the `(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData` method never gets called.

**1. Method that calls token check on new thread:**

```
- (void)awaitTokenCheckCompletion:(void (^) (BOOL success))completion {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, kNilOptions), ^{

        [self checkAccessTokenExpiration];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{   
        });
    });
}
```

The code above calls the `checkAccessTokenExpiration` method, which will fire the `createClientCredentials` method below.

**2. Method that Creates the NSURLConnection:**

```
-(void) createClientCredentials {
    DLog("Getting Access Token");

    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"type=get&id=%@&key=%@",@"id",@"key"];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@authorization/keys", serverURL]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    __attribute__((unused))
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

**3. The (NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData method never gets called:**

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data {
    DLog("gotData");
}
```

Comment: why are you using [self checkAccessTokenExpiration]; inside dispatch async?

Comment: I am trying to prevent the app from calling the URL unless the token is still valid. If the token is not valid, then I need to wait for a new token to be requested before proceeding. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];` is already async. what wont block you main trend..  remove _dispatch_async_ that's useless..

Comment: @Oyeoj, I agree with you, that's what I was trying to point out

Comment: Is there a way for me to prevent a method from continuing until the NSURLConnection is completed?

Comment: @SanjayMohnani Yes!.. and also the answer provided.. hahaha..

Comment: let the delegates do their work..

`- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response`


`- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data`


`- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error`


`- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the delegate inside the block,from the document

> The delegate object for the connection. The connection calls methods on this delegate as the load progresses. Delegate methods are called on the same thread that called this method. For the connection to work correctly, the calling thread’s run loop must be operating in the default run loop mode.

So,try to set the delegate outside the async block

Answer (score 1):

NSURL connection will not be called using dispatch_async block. 
If you calling the same code in main thread by writing conn start it will call the delegates of NSURLConnection.

Initialize and start NSURL Connection :-

```
 NSURLConnection* conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]    
                         initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
 [conn start];
```

You can opt 3 different option to call the api and get data :-

- sendSynchronousRequest
- sendAsynchronousRequest
- initializing NSUrlConnection and telling it to start

Refer this link :-

http://iosdevelopmentjournal.com/blog/2013/01/27/running-network-requests-in-the-background/

Hope this answer will be help you. Thanks